# Connecting Java To SQL

Tags: java, sql, variables

I don't know much about SQL, but I'm fine with Java, I just wanted to know how I can retrieve a variable from my SQL database: 'EasyDirectory'. Like:

```
String test = con.getQuery(query1).get(username);
```

Obviously that doesn't work but I would like a snippet of code that does that. Heres all of my code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Directory {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, SQLException {
      Connection con = null;
      try {
          // Load the JDBC driver
          String driverName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"; // MySQL MM JDBC driver
          Class.forName(driverName);

          // Create a connection to the database
          String serverName = "www.freesql.org";
          String mydatabase = "EasyDirectory";
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName +  "/" + mydatabase; // a JDBC url
          String username = "*********";
          String password = "*********";
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          // Could not find the database driver
      } catch (SQLException e) {
          // Could not connect to the database
      }


    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Directory");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JProgressBar searchprogress = new JProgressBar();
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    final JButton searchbutton = new JButton("Search");
    final JTextField searchfield = new JTextField();
    searchfield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    searchprogress.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 30));
    searchbutton.setLocation(100, 100);

    /* Start Buffered Reader */
    final List<String> housetypes = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Index.txt"));
    while (line != null) {
        line = br.readLine();
        housetypes.add(line);
        String seperation = br.readLine();

    }

    /* Finish Buffered Reader */

    /* Start Content Code */
    final JButton done = new JButton("Done");
    done.setVisible(false);
    JLabel housetype_label = new JLabel();
    JLabel housenumber_label = new JLabel();
    JLabel housestreet_label = new JLabel();
    JLabel housepostal_label = new JLabel();
    JLabel houseplace_label = new JLabel();
    /* Finish Content Code */

    /* Start Button Code */
    done.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            searchfield.setEnabled(true);
            done.setVisible(false);
            searchbutton.setVisible(true);
            searchprogress.setValue(0);
        }
    });
    searchbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            searchprogress.setValue(100);
            String searchquery = searchfield.getText();
            searchprogress.setValue(100);
            searchfield.setEnabled(false);
            done.setVisible(true);
           searchbutton.setVisible(false);
            for (String housetype : housetypes) {
                if (searchquery.equals(housetype)) {
                    String housepath = housetype + "/" + housetype + ".txt";
                    System.out.println(housepath);
                    try {
                        BufferedReader housebr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(housepath));
                        String housename_query = housebr.readLine();
                        String housenumber_query = housebr.readLine();
                        String housestreet_query = housebr.readLine();
                        String houselocality_query = housebr.readLine();
                        String housepostal_query = housebr.readLine();
                        System.out.println(housepostal_query);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    });

    /* Finish Button Code */
    /* Test Field */


    /* End Test Field */

    panel.add(searchfield);
    panel.add(done);
    panel.add(searchbutton);
    panel.add(searchprogress);

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(false);

    /* Start Login Window */
    int passtimes = 3;
    final JFrame login = new JFrame("Login");
    JPanel login_panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel userlabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
    JLabel passlabel = new JLabel(" Password: ");
    JButton loginuser = new JButton("Login");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    final JTextField user_field = new JTextField();
    user_field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    final JPasswordField pass_field = new JPasswordField();
    pass_field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Images/Logo.png");
    ImageIcon space = new ImageIcon("Images/Spacing.png");
    JLabel logo = new JLabel();
    JLabel spacing = new JLabel();
    logo.setIcon(icon);
    login.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,212));
    login_panel.add(logo);
    login_panel.add(userlabel);
    login_panel.add(user_field);
    login_panel.add(passlabel);
    login_panel.add(pass_field);
    login_panel.add(spacing);
    login_panel.add(loginuser);
    login_panel.add(cancel);
    login.add(login_panel);
    login.pack();
    login.setVisible(true);
    login.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    loginuser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String user_input = user_field.getText();
            String pass_input = pass_field.getText();
            String username = "Tom";
            String password = "******";
                if(user_input.equals(username)){
                    if(pass_input.equals(password)){
                        user_field.setEnabled(false);
                        pass_field.setEnabled(false);
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                        login.setVisible(false);
                    }
                    else{//If Password AND Username is incorrect
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Password and/or Username Is Incorrect.", "Failed Login", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                else{ //If Username is incorrect
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Password and/or Username Is Incorrect.", "Failed Login", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
    cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.exit(0);
            }
        });
  }
}
```

Thanks, Helping is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the question? Either way, this is the best starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Comment: Rather than post a wall of code, you should describe the situation properly. What database are you using? What libraries are you trying to use? What exactly doesn't work? What is your database schema? What data are you trying to fetch from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the API of Connection (here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) I would assume that it would have to be something like:

```
 final Statement statement = con.createStatement();
 final ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query1);
 //do stuff with the resultset
 //result.getString(something), see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html
```

On a side-note. I don't really like the fact that you have put both the GUI and the database logic in the same class. You really should separate concerns, by applying the MVC pattern or something similar. For instance, you could create one class for the GUI, one class for to the connection the database, and one class for starting the application and tying the two others together.

Comment: I_Am_A_Noob. I only wanted to learn

Comment: No worries, google MVC, and if you want to learn a lot from a single book you should read Clean Code by Robert Martin. Also, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns